# Custom hook runs on every render even there is no change in dependecies in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I have created a custom hook to fetch data and its `useEffect` gets called every time even there is no change in dependencies. I tried removing all the dependencies and tried to call it once by passing `[]` but it did not work. I am calling the hook from the same component every time.

custom hook:

```
import {useEffect, useState, useCallback} from 'react';

import {animecall} from '../apicalls';

export default function useFetchData(type, sort, format, page) {
  console.log('hook called');
  const [state, setState] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('customhook useeffects');
    const fetchData = async () => {
      setLoading(true);
      const data= await animecall(type, sort, format, page);
      setState((prevstate) => [...prevstate, ...data]);
      setLoading(false);
    };

    fetchData();
  }, [type, sort, format, page]);
  console.log(state);
  return {data: state, loading};
}
```

home.js:

```
const Home = React.memo(
  ({compProp, name}) => {
    console.log('homeSlider');
   
    const {data, loading} = useFetchData('Movie', 'TRENDING_DESC', 'TV', 1);

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
       some jsx
      </View>
    );
  },
  (prevProps, nextProps) => {
    if (prevProps.compProp !== nextProps.compProp) {
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  },
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
useEffect(() => {
console.log('customhook useeffects');
const fetchData = async () => {
  setLoading(true);
  const data= await animecall(type, sort, format, page);
  setState((prevstate) => [...prevstate, ...data]);
  setLoading(false);
};
```

}, []);

Comment: tried passing the empty dependency already...It did not work

Comment: remove this one too:   fetchData();